# Calculate quantiles for a score/ranking system (PHP / MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are two tables:

Table **user**:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | user_name |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |   Alice   |
|  2 |   Steve   |
|  3 |   Tommy   |
+----+-----------+
```

Table **result**:

```
+----+---------+-------+-------------+
| id | user_id | score |  timestamp  |
+----+---------+-------+-------------+
|  1 |    1    |   22  |  1410793838 |
|  2 |    1    |   16  |  1410793911 |
|  3 |    2    |    9  |  1410793920 |
|  4 |    1    |   27  |  1410794007 |
|  5 |    3    |   32  |  1410794023 |
+----+---------+-------+-------------+
```

What I have so far is a "top 3", which works great and looks like this:

```
SELECT MAX(m.score) AS score, u.user_name
FROM result AS r
INNER JOIN user AS u ON r.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY r.user_id
ORDER BY r.score DESC
LIMIT 3;

+-------+-----------+
| score | user_name |
+-------+-----------+
|   32  |   Tommy   |
|   27  |   Alice   |
|    9  |   Steve   |
+-------+-----------+
```

The table is actually filled with hundreds of results, this is just an example. I'm looking for a compact algorithm to get the rank of a specific user in relation to all other users in %. The goal is to output something like "you are in the top 5%/10%/20%/50%" or "you are below average". While it's easy to determine if someone is below average (score < AVG(score)), I have no clue how to determine the other ranks.

Comment: Without any table structure or sample data we'd only be guessing at a solution for you. Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Make use of MySQL's [`AVG()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-avg/) aggregate function. There's also `MAX`, `MIN` and `COUNT` amongst others.

Comment: Sorry, I added a sample scenario & hope it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got all correctly, it's just relative maximum calculation:

```
SELECT
  user_name,
  MAX(score) AS max_score,
  CASE
    WHEN ROUND(100*MAX(score)/maximum, 2)>=95 THEN 'In top 5%'
    WHEN ROUND(100*MAX(score)/maximum, 2)>=90 THEN 'In top 10%'
    WHEN ROUND(100*MAX(score)/maximum, 2)>=75 THEN 'In top 25%'
    WHEN ROUND(100*MAX(score)/maximum, 2)>=50 THEN 'In top 50%'
    WHEN ROUND(100*MAX(score)/maximum, 2)>=0 THEN 'Below average'
  END AS score_mark
FROM
  `result`
    INNER JOIN `user`
      ON `result`.user_id=`user`.id
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT MAX(score) AS maximum FROM `result`) AS init
GROUP BY
  user_id
```

So, counting from maximum score per all table and grouping it for specific user. Check the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f9ebf/7).

As mentioned below, this counting method involves simple way to determine average (i.e. all it's based on total maximum). This may be not the thing which is needed. By that I mean, that if question is about calculation *relative* position according to *other scores* (not maximum) - then it's more complicated:

```
  SELECT
    maxs.*,
    @num:=@num+1 AS order_num,
    CASE
      WHEN 100*(@num-1)/(user_count-1) <=   5 THEN 'In top 5%'
      WHEN 100*(@num-1)/(user_count-1) <=  10 THEN 'In top 10%'
      WHEN 100*(@num-1)/(user_count-1) <=  25 THEN 'In top 25%'
      WHEN 100*(@num-1)/(user_count-1) <=  50 THEN 'In top 50%'
      WHEN 100*(@num-1)/(user_count-1) <= 100 THEN 'Below average'
    END AS score_mark
  FROM
    (SELECT
      user_name,
      MAX(score) AS max_score
    FROM
      `result`
        INNER JOIN `user`
          ON `result`.user_id = `user`.id
    GROUP BY
      user_id
    ORDER BY
      max_score DESC) AS maxs
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT 
        @num:=0,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
      FROM
        `result`) AS init
```

-since now we must first re-count our positions and later build relative calculations over that. Here is the corresponding [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2c98/11). Here, however, I'm applying linear formula to count 1-st position as "zero" and last position as "100". If that's not an intention (there will be edge-cases, like "3" in "50%" for "5 total" in fiddle) - then you may change divisor to `user_count`

Comment: In the 4th condition I think you want `=50`

Comment: I think your results aren't correct. say, there are 10 scores, minimum: 0, maximum 10, average ~7. data: (1,2,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10) there are only 2 scores below the average, and your algorithm states the ones with the average score as top 50% (top 30% computed).

Comment: That depends of what to count as "average" value, which in my case is 50% from total maximum. Both cases are acceptable, but work differently. Thus, it's up to OP to decide, if suggested algorithm in my answer fits his requirements.

Comment: exactly, i it just looked strange to me, if there is one score say 10000 and all the other ones are bellow 100 ;) so your score can be bellow 50% of the maximum score, but you as player are in the top 10% as player.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller well, it's a valid point. And - interesting task in any case. Thus, I've added extended explanations and solution to that too

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version

```
    SELECT user_name, score,(CASE 
        WHEN score BETWEEN  @max-((@max-@min)/10) AND @max THEN  '10'
        WHEN score BETWEEN  @max-((@max-@min)/5) AND @max THEN  '20'
        WHEN score BETWEEN  @max-((@max-@min)/2) AND @max THEN  '50'
        ELSE 'more50' 
        END) as rangescore,
user_name 
FROM result r
INNER JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.id,
(SELECT @max :=  MAX(score) FROM result)x,
(SELECT @min :=  MIN(score) FROM result)y
ORDER BY score DESC
```

You can use `AVG(score)` instead of `MAX` f you want to compare the average score of the user.

Or remove the aggregate functions and GROUP BY if you want every score.

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a6568/5)

[FIDDLE GROUP](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a6568/7)

Comment: Nice example, just have one query , why you have used Divide by 10 for 10% , Divide by 5 for 20% , Divide by 2 for 50% Inside the CASE ? please explain the logic

Comment: @PragneshKaria Well it gets the difference between max and min gets the "meat" of the range so this is divided by 10 to give 10% and this 10 % is further substracted from max.SO now it searches for values between max and max -10%.Use real values,it will become clearer.

Comment: @Machoke Well those separate queries can be JOINed to the main query,but no problem,pick the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now with your new declarations, I will provide you another solution:

As you said you can use PHP and MySQL togheter, I provide you a combined one.

You want to compute your quantiles (to have an idea what this is [quantiles on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile)), because if you have a top scorer with about 10000 points and all other players just have 100 points and below, the ones with 100 points are in the top 5% as player, but there score is under 50% of the top scorer.

With this in mind, we can count the number of players, get the score at the wanted percent of players and compare, were the players score fits in.

First select all the maximas, minimas, counter etc.

```
SELECT
 COUNT(`result`.`score`) `count`,
 MAX(`result`.`score`) `max`,
 MIN(`result`.`score`) `min`,
 AVG(`result`.`score`) `avg`
FROM
 `result`
GROUP BY
 `result`.`user_id`
ORDER BY
 `result`.`score` DESC
```

After you have the complete data, you can compute your quantiles.

```
SELECT
 `result`.`score`
FROM
 `result`
GROUP BY
 `result`.`user_id`
ORDER BY
 `result`.`score` DESC
LIMIT FLOOR($count*$percent), 1
//where $count is the value from the first query and $percent is the wanted quantile e.g. 5%
```

After that you know the value for your quantile and you can compare the actual value with the ones here.

```
//where $percentNN is the score from the previous query
if($score > $percent50) echo "top 50%";
if($score > $percent20) echo "top 20%";
if($score > $percent10) echo "top 10%";
if($score > $percent5) echo "top 5%";
```

maybe, we can combine the multiple queries to one.

Comment: I provided a new answer, please have a look.